# Does casez consider wires assigned z as high impedance during synthesis?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I am designing a R3000 MIPS processor, and for the instruction decoder, want to give a casez such that for cases involving immediate instructions eg ADDI, ANDI, I provide the bits 6:0 as z. I just want to know here {opcode, func} does it get synthesized to a high impedance open connection when the case is z?

```
module Instr_decoder (
    input  logic [31:0]  instr,
    output logic         regDest, 
    output logic         jump,
    output logic         branch,
    output logic         memtoReg,
    output logic         memRead,
    output logic         memWrite,
    output logic         ALUSrc,
    output logic         signExtendInstruction,
    output logic         immediateInstruction,
    output logic         regWrite);

    logic immediate_i;
    logic [5:0] opcode;
    logic [4:0] rs;
    logic [4:0] rt;
    logic [4:0] rd;
    logic [15:0] immediate_data;
    logic [4:0] shamt;
    logic [5:0] func;
    logic [25:0] target;

    assign opcode = instr[31:26];
    assign shamt = instr[10:6];
    assign func = instr[5:0];
    assign target = instr[25:0];
    assign immediate_i = (opcode == (ADDI || ANDI || ORI || SLTI || XORI));

    always_comb
    begin
        casez({opcode, func}

           {6'h00, 6'h20} :  ADD = 1;
           {6'h08,  6'dz} :  ANDI = 1;
```

Comment: Indeed, I can. But since I am running my simulations on Modelsim, which unfortunately doesn't show synthesis reports, I am unable to comprehend. The other option would be to synthesize this small block of code, and go on like that for every sub-block, but then that would be an unnecessary process, since this is just a very small part of the entire design.

Comment: Also, I know that z is a synthesizes to an open(no) connection, but does casez take that into account was my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can compile and execute on a simulator is potentially synthesizable. It comes down to whether or not the tool you are using has an algorithm to recognize the code and map it to a hardware implementation.

BTW, one typically uses the `?` character instead of `z` in a Verilog numeric literal to represent a *don't care* value in a `casez` statement.